# Commonising parts of Markdown READMEs

Tags: github, nuget, markdown

I maintain a few tiny Nuget Packages.

- The Github project page needs a README file.
- The Nuget page needs a README file.

There is a very heavy overlap between what I want on those two pages ... but they're not identical.
There's stuff that want on the Nuget page, that I don't want on the GitHub README, and v.v.

Currently I solve this, by having 2 README files, which I try to keep in sync, for the duplicated sections.

This makes me sad :(

---

Is there any way to commonise text shared across multiple README files, the Markdown format.

Ideally, I guess I'm imagining some sort of "include block" syntax, that refers to smaller `Section.md` files, so that my two main READMEs are just a list of which sections to include?

Comment: Why not use one of those `Actions`, next to `Pull requests` tab, to make a custom include syntax. The bash is limited to prevent bitcoin miners, but that is doable.

Comment: Markdown, by itself, does not provide functionality for including other files. You would need to use a templating system of some kind. Either something in bash, as suggested my Matteo, or something more dedicated like [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/), which is probably implemented in a language you know.